# MVC ASP.NET Multiple Views Based on a Single Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to write a mobile Web application (MVC), where I have been given the UI Design that I need to work to and I am not sure of the best approach and was looking for any recommendations.

To simplify the project:

- The 1st view asks for a number
- The 2nd view asks for a category
- Based on the logic of the first two values, I can show up to 6 different forms/views each collecting different data pieces.

This data then gets written to a single SQL table

I am not sure if I should:

- Have one controller and one model, and I just keep track of which View needs to be shown within that controller
  OR
- Have mutiple models, each based on a previous model
  OR
- Use panels (ie. used to this with WebForms), and make these panels visible again based on tracking which section needed to be viewed.

Any advice would be appreciated,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the Models.

**Case 1:**
There's only going to be one database table (i.e. one survey)
If there's going to be only one database table, you'll only need one controller and one View.

For example:

```
public class Survey
{
    public String Answer1 { get; set; }
    public String Answer2 { get; set; }
    public String Answer3 { get; set; }
}
```

The view can ask the first questions, and accordingly display the appropriate fields. So only the final Submit button will be a `HTTP Post`. All the previous buttons will just perform a simple JavaScript action.

**Case 2:**
The first questions are used to decide which survey the user should take.

I'll have an Action that returns an intial View. The view does a HttpPost to another Action (`ShowSurvey`)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowSurvey(string id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        // display the appropriate View here.
    }
}
```

`ShowSurvey` would that take a parameter using which you know which survey you're supposed to display. This action will have it's own View/View(s). (One view if all the survey questions are similar. Else you might need to have more views).

This would be my approach BTW. Critics are welcome!

**UPDATE:**

I read your question again and you've mentioned you've got only one SQL Table. So yeah Case 1 will be the easiest way.

Display the initial questions. Decide what to show etc. at runtime using JavaScript. Once the user has finished answering all the questions, you can show him (or enable) the Submit button that'll perform a `HTTP Post` back to your action and commit the data to the Database.

<sub>PS: I've used the word survey just because questions remind me of them :P</sub>

Comment: This approach worked well. I added "nStage" to the model, and used that value in my Switch.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how these two are related? Is the value entered into the first field have influence on the second? I'd build some simple two field model or - since I like pass to view explicit structures, I would add another field to the model containing list of available options, so it would be:

```
public class MySimpleModel{        
    public int MyNumber{get; set;}
    public string MyCategory{get; set;}
    public List<string> Categories{get; set;}
}
```

and then post it controller (by regular form submit or ajax):

```
public class MyController:Controller{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MySimpleModel model){
        if(model==null)
            return Index();
        if (model.MyNumber>3 && model.MyCategory=="xxx")
            return View("View1",model);
        //etc. 

    }
}
```

About user interface - make it user friendly and logical. You didn't wrote anything about requirements, so it's hard do advise you :)